# C# Discover the LocalEndPoint AddressFamily port number

Tags: c#, port, tcpclient

When I establish a tcp connection to a server using the TcpClient class, is there any way to find out the source port of this connection?
I am trying to implement the exec protocol and stderr port seems to always be source port + 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `((IPEndPoint) tcpClient.Client.LocalEndPoint).Port` after establishing the connection.

Comment: Port does not seem to be a property of LocalEndPoint.

Comment: Ah, forgot to cast to IPEndPoint.

Comment: So cast LocalEndPoint as a IPEndPoint and should work ok? I will try :)

Comment: Hooray. Thankyou very much! The cast worked fine!
A++++++++++++++

Answer (score 0):

Solved :)

> Client sends TCP port number (decimal
>   ascii, null-terminated) of stderr
>   port. If the first byte is a NULL,
>   then server won't make any stderr
>   connection.